# VB.NET Combo Box with multiple fields to select from

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, combobox

I'm porting an Access database I wrote over to VB.NET and while I've used Access for 25 years, I've used VB.NET for 2 days so I'm unclear what the capabilities are.

In my Access form, I have a Combo Box which allows the user to select a part record from a table. Using Access I can show multiple columns to the user making a selection - PartID, Description, notes, whatever. However once the part is selected and the combo box is closed, I show only the unique part ID.  The other columns help the user choose but make the form look really cluttered.

In my VB.NET form, I set the ValueMember to the PartID. But I only know how to set the DisplayMember to a single field. I created a composite field "PartID | Description | Notes" but then that's what appears even after the selection is made.

Is it possible in VB.NET to show one thing when the box is open and another thing once the selection has been made?

```
    qry = "SELECT PartID, cast(PartID as string) & " | " & [partName] AS PartString
            FROM [Part_List]
            GROUP BY PartID, cast(PartID as string) & " | " & [partName]
            ORDER BY PartID;"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, conn)
    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim tblPN As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(tblPN)

    ChoosePartNum.DataSource = tblPN
    ChoosePartNum.DisplayMember = "PartString"
    ChoosePartNum.ValueMember = "PartID"
    ChoosePartNum.SelectedIndex = -1
```

Comment: Use a DataGridView instead of a ComboBox.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would achieve my goal. Can you expand on that? My understanding of a DataGridView is that it has a fixed size and appears as a table (or grid I guess). I'm looking for a compact control that can expand when necessary and show specific information

Comment: You can use two Grids, bound by a Relation created using a DataSet (~similar to a Master/Detail view) or otherwise generated by adding DataBindings *manually*. There's no ComboBox like that in WinForms (since this is the Platform you happen to be using). You can also use a  ListView or a TreeView as selector, it's a design choice, depending on layour preferences. You should probably try not to replicate 1:1 what you did in a different, specific, environment and use the tools and methods available in the one you're using now.

Comment: You have many, many other choices, besides what I briefly described here.

Comment: A combo box on a form is far better and less real estate then a data grid etc. The user was used to a mutli-column combo box that Access has. I can't imagine that attempting a data grid of some type is going to work near as well as a combo box.  I think some kind of popup form would work - but certainly miss the multi-column combo box, and the same object model allowed a multiple column list box - they were nice and handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do. I was doing that in MS Access too but it was more than 20 years ago.

I agree with Jimi. From a design point of view, trying to reproduce Access-like features in a new environment is not a great idea.

Users are familiar with Winforms controls and have certain expectations in term of UI layout and consistency. If you are building a new UI from scratch you should take the opportunity to redesign it and modernize it. Don't just carry 25-year old habits over. Especially if you are not the only user of that application, because you don't want people to think that your coding methods are stuck in the 20th century...

> Is it possible in VB.NET to show one thing when the box is open and
>   another thing once the selection has been made?

If you really want to achieve this behavior you need to use **combo box events**. The two events you need would be [DropDownClosed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownclosed?view=netcore-3.1) and [DropDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdown?view=netcore-3.1).

Here is how it can be done:

```
  Private Sub ComboBox1_DropDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DropDown
        With Me.ChoosePartNum
            .DisplayMember = "composite field"
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_DropDownClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DropDownClosed
        With Me.ChoosePartNum
            .DisplayMember = "PartID"
        End With
    End Sub
```

The trick is to change the `DisplayMember` property whenever the combo box is folded/unfolded by the user. The underlying value remains the same.

I don't know if you require autocomplete from keyboard or have other needs. A `treeview` or `listview` sound like obvious alternatives. But you said you want a 'compact' control. Here you go.

Comment: That's a very elegant way to do this - I'll try that. And I'm eager to move away from mimicking Access design but first things first while I learn how to replicate my app in VB.NET and SqlServer, then I can move forward.